# positioning text of anchor within a div

Tags: html, css, text, anchor

Given the markup

```
<div id="header">
<a href="cattle.html" class="current">Cattle Farms</a>
</div>
```

And style

```
#header
{
width: 960px;
height: 200px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#header a
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
font-size: 25px;
}
```

How whould I go about placing/positioning/aligning the text "cattle farms" so that it sits 20px from the left and 20px from the bottom in such a manner that it does not break the a out of the div visually even when looking it with Firebug.

Comment: Is this the question: how to stretch that text to full screen width?

Comment: @Stano: No the question is very clear. How to place the text within a in a div.

Comment: @Jawad: If people are asking questions about your question, your question is not clear.

Comment: @Blender: Ok. My own answer should make it clear than.

Comment: Puffffffff. People use downvotes just because they are given a right to do so.

Comment: Reversed their stupid downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a `<span>` to the anchor and add some padding to that. Like this:

```
<div id="header">
  <a href="cattle.html" class="current"><span>Cattle Farms</span></a>
</div>
```

And add these additional styles:

```
#header a span {
padding-left: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

EDIT:

Also, add overflow: hidden to the header.

```
#header {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Man a is set to display: block and height/width: 100% which means a has the same height/width as div which is 960px X 200px

Comment: @Jawad I've added a fiddle. I think it's what you're after.

Comment: Can't take away 100% width and height on a since, and it should be obvious from the markup, that the whole area is now clickable.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize the "red area" should be clickable. How about adding `overflow: hidden;` to #header and keeping the width/height of the anchor?

Comment: Add overflow: hidden; and what style. Your above one?

Comment: I have updated my answer, but like I said in my previous comment,  add `overflow: hidden` to #header.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? See my answer. What your code does is make the 20px of padding "NOT CLICKABLE".

Comment: Really?! http://jsfiddle.net/u3M5C/2/  But I guess you figured out your problem and don't need our help anyway.

Comment: No. I appreciate your answer and thank you for it. It's just that you answer uses extra markup. Second look where the text is in you fiddel. It's 20 px from the top and I want it to be 20px from the bottom. Maybe because span is an inline ellment and if display: block is set on span with also 100% width/height, It may work. Any idea why line-height does the trick and that also withy 350px value.

Comment: Ok... Line-height basically centers the text in the line (if that made sense). The header has a height of 200px and the line-height is 350px. So the line of text is centered (vertically) in the 350px... basically 175px from the top. That just puts it in the correct position relating to the size of the header. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you for clearing that up. If font-size and line-height is the same it makes a perfect v-align and the value 350px taken into account the size of the text which is 25px. Thanks a million and three.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `position: relative` on the parent container:

**CSS**:

```
#header {
  position: relative;

  width: 960px;
  height: 200px;
}

#header a {
  position: absolute;

  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: That much I knew but as I said it breaks the a out of the div.

Comment: I can do the same with a{position: relative; top: 180px; left: 20px;}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking away the 100% width and height. By doing this, you'll be able to place it within the header. If you don't, you're expanded to the size of the header, so there's no room to change your placement.

Since it's a block element, you can do this a few ways.
You can either use margin to "push" it away from other elements (if you decide to add more on top of it). Or you can you use "position: relative" and "top" or "left". I would recommend using this with a %. I tried this code and it achieved the effect you were looking for I think:

```
#header{
width: 960px;
height: 200px;
}

#header a {
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 95%;
}
```

Comment: Can't take away 100% width and height on a since, and it should be obvious from the markup, that the whole area is now clickable.

Comment: Ahhh... I gotcha. That makes sense. In that case you'll want to take Connor's approach and add a span within the anchor tag and position that within the clickable area.

Comment: Can't take Connor's approach as I am fraid of the terminator. (joke). Any way I figured it out see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I have no idea why this works. But it does

```
div#header a
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
text-indent: 20px;
line-height: 350px;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually puzzled why this works as well. Any ideas anyone? The child's line-height is bigger than the parent's height, yet the parent doesn't grow, nor is their overflow.

Comment: @PaulCalabro: I am not sure neither I have good enough knowledge in font theroy but the line-height (leading?) may get "cut-off" at the 200px limit.

Comment: The weird thing is it doesn't. If you were to use 450px for the line-height, it breaks out of the box. Very strange!

Comment: @PaulCalabro: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044983/how-does-exactlly-line-height-work-in-this-case