# How does exactlly line-height work in this case

Tags: html, css, text-indent

In this question [positioning text of anchor within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997161/positioning-text-of-anchor-within-a-div/11997261#11997261) and given the same code which I repeat here:

**HTML Markup**

```
<div id="header"> 
    <a href="cattle.html" class="current">Cattle Farms</a> 
</div>
```

**CSS Style**

```
#header a { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    display: block; 
    font-size: 25px; 
}
```

**Answer**

```
div#header a { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    display: block; 
    text-indent: 20px; 
    line-height: 350px; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnX9n/1/)

My question is why does not the line-height make the a break out of the div

Comment: @Paul Calabro: Maybe others can come up with a better insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does break out of the div. If you put a `span` inside the `a` tag and give it a display of inline-block (and a background-color so you can see it) you'll realize it does. Remember the span inherits the line-height. Take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/fnX9n/6/

Give the `a` a bigger line-height and without anything else you'll also be able to realize it is breaking out of the div: http://jsfiddle.net/fnX9n/7/

Comment: Look it up in FF with Firebug with no span element. The Firebug shows that the a element is contained with in the div#header even if i give line-height: 500px;

Comment: Its just the text that moves. Not the anchor.

Comment: I wasn't warned about your comments. I'm too tired too answer now. I'll get back tomorrow. Sorry... But, basically, since you set a specific height on the a element (with a display of block), it's no longer the line-height that determines it's height - it's the... well, the height. The line-height still takes effect, it just no longer determines the elements height, since you chose to set it yourself when you set the height.